# Error: "Could not find valid value for id" when registering - but only when registering from countries which are far away

Tags: civievent

We have a CiviCRM install, where this error happens - but only occasionally! 
It's a multilingual site (english and german), and they have participants from all over the world.
It seems to me, that the error happens especially with people fomr "less developed countries", and we do find quite a number of these cases in the logfile (or people complaining via email), but I personally was not able to reproduce that error.

The system is up to date:

CiviCRM 5.11.0, Drupal 7.65, PHP 7.2

Excerpt from the CiviCRM logfile (ConfigAndLog)

```
Feb 25 00:23:56  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array (
    [message] => Could not find valid value for id
    [code] => )


Feb 25 00:23:56  [info] $backTrace = #0
/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381):
CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrac e", TRUE)
#1 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Request.php(121): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Could not find valid value for id")
#2 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/StateMachine/Registration.php(52):
CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve("id", "Positive", Object
(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)
#3 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Controller/Registration.php(47):
CRM_Event_StateMachine_Registration->__construct(Objec
t(CRM_Event_Controller_Registration), TRUE)
#4 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(304): CRM_Event_Controller_Registration->__construct("Event Registration",
TR UE, "null", NULL, "false")
#5 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:15))
#6 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#7 /html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#8 /html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("event", "register")
#9 /html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#10 {main}

 (
     [message] => Could not find valid value for id
     [code] => )
```

The webserver's access log says:

```
154.100.184.0 - - [25/Feb/2019:00:23:54 +0100] "POST /civicrm/event/register HTTP/2.0" 200 1686
"https://******.de/civicrm/event/register?id=41&language=en"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
******.de
154.100.184.0 - - [25/Feb/2019:00:23:56 +0100] "GET /sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/crm-i.css HTTP/2.0" 200 1024
"https://******.de/civicrm/event/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0" ******.de
154.100.184.0 - - [25/Feb/2019:00:23:56 +0100] "GET /sites/all/modules/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
HTTP/2.0" 200 31000 "https://******.de/civicrm/event/register"
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
******.de
154.100.184.0 - - [25/Feb/2019:00:23:56 +0100] "GET /sites/all/modules/civicrm/css/civicrm.css HTTP/2.0" 200 83907
"https://******.de/civicrm/event/register" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
6.1; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0" ******.de
```

I have no clue, where to look at...

Comment: I am dealing with this as well. Are you finding it with only countries that the time is ahead?

Comment: Hey, that could be an idea... I am not able to check that completely - but as far as I can oversee, all the errors are come from countries, where time is ahead, indeed!

Comment: So, it might be a good idea to deal with the converting from "datetime" to "timestamp". See:

https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen

I will look for that tomorrow.